# Any functions to work with bitmask?

Tags: php

I have `int` field representing bitmask. Is there any functions available to work with bitmask? `issetBit`, `unsetBit`, `setBit`?

Thank you

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use [bitwise operators](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.bitwise.php). But if you want functions, here you have some.

```
function issetBit(& $mask, $bit) {
    return (bool)($mask & (1 << $bit));
}

function unsetBit(& $mask, $bit) {
    $mask &= ~(1 << $bit);
}

function setBit(& $mask, $bit) {
    $mask |= (1 << $bit);
}
```

Usage: first argument is your current bitmask; second argument is the number of the bit (zero-based). I.e. `issetBit($mask, 2)` equals `(bool)($mask & 4)`
You cannot test/set/unset more than one bit at once with those functions though.

Comment: thanks, I am trying to learn as much about using these in PHP, I think the main motivation is that it is a challenge for me and not beginner type code IMO.  Here is my questions/answers for my post so far if you care to look/contribute ... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5319475/bitmask-in-php-for-settings

Comment: If you get a chance, could you possibly show an example using your functions above, please?

Answer (score 2):

You want the Bitwise Operators:
http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.bitwise.php