# How i can set several definite bits of integer to concrete values?

Tags: php, binary, bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators

I am trying to do some work with permissions stored in integer using bitwise operators, and went stuck trying to set several definite bits to `1` or `0` in one line.

My current code is:

```
function setPermission(int $permissions, int $type, bool $value)
{
    return ($permissions & ~$type) | /* There is what i don't know how to do */;
}

echo setPermission(2|4|16, 4|8,    false); // 2|16
echo setPermission(2|4|16, 4|8,    true ); // 2|4|8|16
echo setPermission(1|2|4,  4|8|16, false); // 1|2
```

By analyzing the problem i find out how to do the first part of the function and that the second one must be equal to $type when `$value` is `true`, and to `0` when `$value` is `false`, but i don't know how to do that in the easiest way.

I draw your attention that parameter `$type` may be any integer, not only the power of two.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Bitmask in PHP for settings?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5319475/bitmask-in-php-for-settings)

Comment: edited, in last paragraph i pointed out the difference

Comment: With your devilish skills you should easily understand that manipulation of each bit is independent of other bits... so there is no difference whether you are setting one single bit or multiple of them.

Comment: I think you are not right.
`$number = ($number & ~(1 << $n)) | ($new_bit << $n)` won't be working for me at least for the reason that there is no valid `$n` when `$type` isn't a power of two.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to perform a different operation in `setPermission` dependent on whether `$value` is true or false. Your current code only implements the case where you want to clear permissions (`$value = false`).

```
function setPermission(int $permissions, int $type, bool $value)
{
    if ($value)
        return $permissions | $type;
    else
        return $permissions & ~$type;
}
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/pvgBW)